# How to extract href value from an html response in postman

Tags: postman, cheerio

I have been trying to figure out how to extract the value from of a href attribute from an html response and have not had any luck.

I have the following response:

```
<body id="bodytag" class="taskTab">
    <script></script>
    <div id="downloads">
        <div class="files"><a
            href="/download/b521086a-965e-44f9-a042/file.pdf/files">Files.pdf</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have gathered that I can use `cheerio` to load the html and potentially get the value but the only thing that I have managed to get is the text `Files.pdf`. What I need is the path in the `href` attribute so that I can store it in a variable to use in a sub0sequent request.

This is just one example of what I have tried:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
console.log($('.files', '#downloads').text());
```

I also tried to use xpath without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response); 
console.log($('.files').attr('href'));
```

This should return you the href of the element. Documentation [here](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#-selector-context-root-)

Comment: That will result in an `undefined` error. What worked was `$('.files a').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

I was close:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
var href = $('.files a').attr('href');
pm.environment.set('downloadLink', href);
```